# Reading images using CV2 library is too slow

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, opencv

I am writing a code to read all the images in a directory and store them in a numpy array, for some reason the reading of each image lasts about 0.5 seconds, I don't know why it is so slow. I'm using Google Colab and I'm reading the images from my Drive.

I have the following code:

```
# Shuffle the list of files
random.shuffle(jpg_files)

# Pre-allocate NumPy array with correct shape
n_samples = 10000
width = 112
height = 112
mri_images = np.empty((n_samples, height, width), dtype=np.float32)

# Read and resize the images in batches
i = 0
for jpg_file in jpg_files:
    if i == n_samples:
        break
    # Read image
    mri_image = cv2.imread(jpg_folder_path + '/' + jpg_file, 0)
    # Store in NumPy array
    mri_images[i] = mri_image

    i += 1
```

I am getting for each read times like these for each read times of a minimum of 0.3 seconds. How can I make it faster?

Answer (score 0):

Is it `cv2.imread` which is really slow or simply `mri_images[i] = mri_image` which converts the output format (certainly requiring 4x more memory) ? Reading a jpg image can be slow for many reasons: either the disk is a slow HDD or it is a slow network device or you read too many files, or the actual jpg file takes time to be decoded (jpg images requires a lot of computational steps to be decoded since they are heavily compressed). The later can be speed up using a **parallel read**. Others cannot be much optimized (at least not easily).

If you read 10000 files, then you should not be surprised of this to be slow. Requesting 20_000-30_000 files/s is not reasonable (each read required at least 3 IO operations and HDD/SSD have a limited number of IOPS -- typically about <200 IOPS for an HDD, 80K IOPS for basic SATA SSD and 200K-400K IOPS for a good recent Nvme SSD). You should pack images in a big file so to reduce the number of required IOPS. There are **specialized file formats for that like HDF5** common in scientific computing.